# Python global variable and wcf solution guidance

Tags: python, web-services, wcf, kivy

My question might be  lame since I recently started learning python, following is my question:

1. I am trying to develop a python cross platform app for android and windows, I need how to use a variable defined at App level through out the program (global but not just at module level, it is mainly for passing user id to all forms)
2. A WCF solution for this program, or any alternative technology ( I am new to web building too, but have used WCF previously).

Also, global variables is really tough to understand in python since I am from VB; most of the articles I have gone through say that global variables in a module, but what about application level or like variables/classes instantiated at APP class/build Module in a kivy program.

Any hints on how to develop/architecture guidelines or just pointing in right direction to learn them is of great help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand most of your question, but rather than using global variables (which is bad for all the normal reasons), it may often be appopriate to store variables as attributes or properties of your `App` class. You can access this at any time with `App.get_running_app()`, so it's easy to access them again.

Comment: So I will be using this "App.get_running_app().__dict__" to store values so that they can be accessed globally.  Thank you for that, kivy documentation is not clear for me on how to use that; your answer is much useful compared to marking as a bad question.  Thank you for your time.

Comment: You don't need to care about the existence of `__dict__` in any special way, just store stuff as attributes of your class. You may also find it useful to use kivy properties.

Comment: that is a solution, also, if not using kivy, how to get a global variable solution?